# Add Delay to Agora Broadcast?

Tags: javascript, python, streaming, live, agora.io

Is it possible to add a delay to an Agora broadcast? Maybe something like 30 seconds. The goal of this would be to improve stream quality in the event of short network problems. Would I have to save the video and audio frames myself to play after a delay, and if so could you point me somewhere to read about that?

Or would this not even help to improve stream quality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve is called buffering. 
With the delay, you'll watch the stream 30 seconds later. It will not help you.

P.S. Delays are only used for TV kinds of live events, like censoring stuff, for instance, curse words etc...

Agora.io's streaming codecs are pretty neat they optimize automatically but you can always set a [Video Profile](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/video_profile_web?platform=Web) and pick something reasonable for you.

This will save you some bandwidth.